# Как сделать проверку на возможность изменить роль?

Tags: node.js, бот, discord

Пишу своего *Discord* бота.

В одном из действий бот должен выдавать/забирать роль. Я это реализовывал с помощью:

```
guildMember.roles.remove(take.Id);
```

и

```
guildMember.roles.add(take.Id);
```

Однако, если роль находится выше максимальной роли бота, то при попытки выдать эту роль, в консоли появляется ошибка:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Как можно сделать проверку на возможность выдачи этой роли? Если бот не может выдать роль (нет прав) - return.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
try {
  await guildMember.roles.add(take.Id);
} catch(err) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Если оставить скобки пустыми: ```} catch () { SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'```

А если дать catch название, то снова выпадает ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions```

Comment: поправил слегка

Comment: Избегайте давать код без какго-либо описания. Автоматом попадёт в очередь проверок как низкокачественный.

Answer (score 1):

Смог найти такое решение:

```
guildMember.roles.add(pos.Id)
        .catch(() => {
            return;
        });
```

Comment: Александр, вы в вопросе написали "Если бот не может выдать роль (нет прав) - return.", так вот - ваш вариант не "делает ретурн", вы просто подавляете исключение и продолжаете выполнение программы. Предложенный мной вариант делает именно то, что вы запросили. (т.е. я не говорю, что ответ не правильный, просто объясняю принципиальную разницу)